# How to make my current navigation bar responsive (ASP.NET)

Tags: css, asp.net, html, visual-studio

I am currently working on a web-form project and have created a navigation bar. I was wondering what I'd have to do in order to make the navigation bar responsive so that when the window size is readjusted, the navigation bar will change accordingly instead of squishing together.

The code that I am using is as follows:

**Master.site page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NestedMasterPage1.master.cs" Inherits="TGASAttempt.NestedMasterPage1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="TGASlogo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Home Page.aspx">Home Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/">List1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/">List2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/">List3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/">List4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/">List5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Signup.aspx">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Login.aspx">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </header>

        <div>

        </div>
</body>
</html>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="nestedContent" runat="server">


                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </asp:Content>
```

**Stylesheet.CSS**

```
body {
    padding-left:200px;
    padding-right:200px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #F0EFE8;    
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.container {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

header {
    background: #FFD63C;
}

header::after {
    content: '';
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
    padding:5px 0;
}

nav {
    float:right;
}

nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:35px;
    padding-top:35px;

    position:relative;
}

nav a {
color:#444;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:500;

}

nav a:hover {
    color:#FFF;

}

    nav a::before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 0%;
        transition:all ease-in-out 250ms;
    }

    nav a:hover::before{
        width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `<link>` tags outside of your `<html>` tag? You need to go read some basic tutorials on HTML.

Comment: @mason Because when I put the link tag inside of my html tag, it gives me an error saying "Validation (HTML5): Element 'link' cannot be nested within element 'html'."

Comment: That's because it shouldn't be a direct child of the `<html>` element. It should be part of the `<head>`. It's also not clear why you're defining the `<html>` element on a master page that isn't the root master page.

Comment: @mason It is because I wanted to have a separate master page that is responsible for the web pages that I have created. But either way, that isn't the question I was asking. I wanted to know how it would be possible to make the navigation bar responsive / collapsable.

Comment: It's fine to have nested master pages. But it doesn't make any sense to not have the `<html>` and some of other other necessary elements like `<head>` and `<body>` within it. And it doesn't make sense to have a `<link>` outside of `<html>`. You should only have one root element, and it should be `<html>`. This is just the basics. I know it's not the question you're asking, but it's still *wrong* and you can get undefined behavior when you do silly things like have invalid HTML. You absolutely need to fix it.

Comment: I see, so what parts would you suggest I keep in the nested master site, and which ones to put in the main one? (Thank you a lot for the advice, I am still very new to programming but I am slowly getting there)

Comment: First off, decide if you really need two master pages. The root one will contain the basic HTML structure. If you have a need for multiple different layouts, then I could see two different master pages inheriting from a root master page. But you may not have that in your scenario. Make sure you check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).

Comment: This is completely unrelated to asp.net, let alone Visual Studio. Don't add as much tags as possible, stick to the relevant ones. Also, you need to state what exactly you're expecting your navbar to do. Right now it is in fact responsive, because it changes size along with the window.

Comment: @ChrisG actually, I am using ASP.NET to code this, using visual studio? so it is relevent. ASP.NET just happens to be a mixture of HTML5 and CSS.

Comment: @Zalgawi It's not relevant *at all*. Responsiveness happens in the browser which means it's exclusively client-side. The browser does not know or care about the backend, let alone the editor used to write the code. And that last sentence is just incredibly weird. It suggests you don't know what either of the three are.

Comment: @ChrisG I was only trying to get help with that one question I had... I don't see why I always get swamped by more experienced programmers constantly criticizing me? like I said, I AM STILL NEW to all of this and I'm trying to learn my way up. Hence why I am asking questions on here.

Comment: If you don't want to get "criticized", how about not making dubious assertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @media queries is what you are looking for.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px){
   nav {
       // this styling will have affect when user is using screen with 720px or lower width
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would I go about applying it to mine?

Comment: This is entirely up to you how you want your navbar looking on small screen. You can hide all elements and add all menu contents to hamburger button.

Comment: I was more trying to apply this tutorial to my code, to get the same effect but obviously, my original code is different from how he programmed his navigation bar. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0GxC504Usg&t=376s

Comment: This tutorial is using bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/ Basically what you do with that is adding classes to your HTML tags. First step would be downloading bootstrap library and adding it to your web

Comment: Oh I see, is there a way to have the same effect without using bootstrap? I'm not using JQuery since I'm unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download any of the free responsive theme and try to integrate them in your code. Using a readymade theme is more better approach than to have a quick workaround.

[free responsive theme](https://justfreethemes.com/themes/responsive/)

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.